# UIScrollView Programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I've been unable to find a way of accurately enabling horizontal and vertical scrolling programmatically with Swift (my objects are programmatic thus making using auto layout in IB unfeasible).

The tutorial I followed allows for scrolling both ways as intended. The problem is my button stays in the same spot occupying part of the screen no matter where you scroll. I've had this same result with another tutorial and am quite confused as to why this is happening.

I haven't been able to find an answer to this so I'm assuming some others will find this beneficial.

Here is the code I have. I made a very basic project based on this tutorial: http://koreyhinton.com/blog/uiscrollview-crud.html

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var containerView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let buttonOne = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        
        buttonOne.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 50, 50)
        buttonOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        buttonOne.setTitle("test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction1x1:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        
        self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)
        
        containerView = UIView()
        
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.view.addSubview(buttonOne)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try add button to scrollView or containerView

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly, but there is a small problem in adding buttonOne on the view.

You have added buttonOne on self.view (i.e subview of self.view), not containerView which is on scrollView.

You should use the following code

```
containerView.addSubview(buttonOne)
```

instead of

```
self.view.addSubview(buttonOne)
```

Comment: That makes so much sense yet it would never have occurred to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

So you should use following line

```
containerView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```